# How to create a measuring line in HTML and CSS using nested divs

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add marks under a div at equal distance and then showing a text under each of these markers.

My code:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

#markL0,
#markL25,
#markL50,
#markL75,
#markL100,
#markL125,
#markL150,
#markL175,
#markL200 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 12.5%;
  float: left;
}

#L0,
#L25,
#L50,
#L75,
#L100,
#L125,
#L150,
#L175,
#L200 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 12.4%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="markL0">|</div>
  <div id="markL25">|</div>
  <div id="markL50">|</div>
  <div id="markL75">|</div>
  <div id="markL100">|</div>
  <div id="markL125">|</div>
  <div id="markL150">|</div>
  <div id="markL175">|</div>
  <div id="markL200">|</div>

  <div id="L0">0L</div>
  <div id="L25">25L</div>
  <div id="L50">50L</div>
  <div id="L75">75L</div>
  <div id="L100">100L</div>
  <div id="L125">125L</div>
  <div id="L150">150L</div>
  <div id="L175">175L</div>
  <div id="L200">200L</div>

</div>
```

Using above code, I am trying to achieve this :

[image]

Currently, it looks like this :
[image]

I have put  `width:12.5%;` so that all the 8 marker starting from second can align at equal distance from each other (100/8 = 12.5).

There are two issues I am facing here

1.The last marker `markL200` is not displaying adjacent other divs
2. Text 0L is showing under the second marker. Its suppose to be below the first one.

can you please tell me whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: You have 9 markers, not 8. Try counting next time. Use `width: calc(100% / 9);`

Comment: Did you check my updated answer, solution#1?

Comment: yes. thats very clean..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 9 markers, not 8. Use `width: calc(100% / 9);` and adjust the width of your slider properly. Find the adjusted solution at the end of this post.

### Here's what I'd come up with:

#### See how far CSS can take you...

```css
ol {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: section;
  
}

ol::before {
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% / 9 * 8 + 3px);
}

ol li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
}

ol li::before {
  content: "|";
  font-size: 18px;
}

ol li::after {
  content: counter(section)"L";
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -12px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

ol li:not(:first-child)::after {
  counter-increment: section 25;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

### Your adjusted solution:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% / 9 * 8 + 2px);
}

#markL0,
#markL25,
#markL50,
#markL75,
#markL100,
#markL125,
#markL150,
#markL175,
#markL200 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  float: left;
}

#L0,
#L25,
#L50,
#L75,
#L100,
#L125,
#L150,
#L175,
#L200 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="markL0">|</div>
  <div id="markL25">|</div>
  <div id="markL50">|</div>
  <div id="markL75">|</div>
  <div id="markL100">|</div>
  <div id="markL125">|</div>
  <div id="markL150">|</div>
  <div id="markL175">|</div>
  <div id="markL200">|</div>

  <div id="L0">0L</div>
  <div id="L25">25L</div>
  <div id="L50">50L</div>
  <div id="L75">75L</div>
  <div id="L100">100L</div>
  <div id="L125">125L</div>
  <div id="L150">150L</div>
  <div id="L175">175L</div>
  <div id="L200">200L</div>

</div>
```

And btw, don't use `id` for styling purposes. If many item share the same styles, use a css class:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slider {
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  width: calc(100% / 9 * 8 + 3px);
}

.mark,
.L {
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  float: left;
}

.mark {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.L {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>
    <div class="mark">|</div>

    <div class="L">0L</div>
    <div class="L">25L</div>
    <div class="L">50L</div>
    <div class="L">75L</div>
    <div class="L">100L</div>
    <div class="L">125L</div>
    <div class="L">150L</div>
    <div class="L">175L</div>
    <div class="L">200L</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks much. Its really helpful